# SQlite "Is not existing in"

Tags: sqlite, select

I have the following problem. I want to have an Select statement, where I compare 2 ID's and get the ID's who are in Table 1 and NOT in Table 2. This is my last Try.

```
SELECT * FROM Categories, Stores WHERE Categories.idCategories NOT IN ( Stores.category ) GROUP BY Categories.idCategories
```

is it even possible. According to [this](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html) I should have tried all operators, but I am really no expert in SQL, especially in SQlite, so I might have forgotten something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Categories 
WHERE Categories.idCategories NOT IN ( select category from Stores ) 
GROUP BY Categories.idCategories
```

Comment: beside I don't understand whats the difference between my query and your query it works, thanks :)